# microsoft exchange 2003 and the iPad2

Tags: exchange-2003, ipad

Trying to get my ipad2 phone and other things to work with microsoft exchange, but nothing seems to work. anyone know of a how-to guide to set it up to work with mobile devices? at the moment no mobile devices work with the exchange server, only computer with Outlook, and the web-based email. tried getting an OMA installer to work with it but it caused issues and didnt work at all. I need help, preferrably a step-by-step guide. Exchange is Service Pack 2 as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the documents for setting up [Exchange emails on an iOS](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2480).

Basically **Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars > Add Account > Microsoft Exchange**.

Answer (score 0):

I have not setup an iPad, but if it is anything like the iPhone, the settings you want would be:

servername.com:443

emailaddress@domain.com

password